# Is there any way to handle Google Sheets' date format "mmmmm" token for java?

Tags: datetime, google-sheets-api, simpledateformat

I want to translate all google sheets date pattern tokens using [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#date_and_time_format_tokens) in JAVA. I am having difficulty in the token "mmmmm" which google marks as

> First letter of the month (e.g., "J" for June).

The issue with doing it manually is that some letters may stand for 2 months, like A for {April, August}. Is there any way for me to translate this to any of JAVA's datetime?

PS: I am new to this API, so if there is any other way in which i can handle all these dates which I am missing, that may also be helpful.

Comment: Hi ! So you bascially want to get all your cell date information in the format ```mmmmm``` and you want to get it in a different format right? Are you getting this format after performing a ```GET``` request over the desired cells? Are the dates in the sheet written in the ```mmmmm``` format or in your desired format? If you could share a code sample with no sensitive data of what you are implementing it could be really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced this issue in the past. I found a far better way of dealing with google sheet dates, by using the SERIAL_NUMBER that its API returns.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DateTimeRenderOption

This corresponds to the number of days since 30th December 1899. For example if this SERIAL_NUMBER is 5.25, it means 5 days and 6 hours past 30th December 1899. Offsetting this value to EPOC time and using the timestamp from there is the best way to handle google sheets dates.

Comment: Yes, this is how we finally handled the issue. Sorry didn't update here, had forgotten about it... ;-/.